# React App copy-paste/manually typing link shows page without fetching data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

Suppose I have an e-commerce site, where i want to share product links on social media/send someone via messages. The issue on my app is when I share the link of product page it's not working on new browser where my app not loaded before.

I have checked on redux tools, it shows nothing loaded on it when manually typing the link to product page. After that if I visit homepage and refresh the page then everything gets loaded then everything works fine.

I have tried hash routing, it doesn't work either.

I think there is something wrong with my redux setup. Because static pages are working fine only issue when i share pages that loads data from server.

I'm stuck here. Can anyone help me out please

Comment: Have you installed a service worker? Turn off it first.

Comment: Thanks but I have not installed it separately, it was built-in with CRA and I have checked with disabling service worker from index.js but still no luck!